# appcenter react native ios, `index.ios.js` was not found

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

using react native for appcenter, how can I set the build to use index.js?

I'm getting the following error:

```
error The resource `/Users/runner/work/1/s/index.ios.js` was not found
```

Can I specify this on the prebuild script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a while of digging, this was the fix:

just add

> index.ios.js

file on the root of the project

And in the file,  import the base for my project

```
require ('./src/index.native')
```

After that the build was fine